# Regular Lindelöf space is paracompact

Tags: general-topology

I thought I had a reasonable understanding of basic general topology, but I have been struggling somewhat with the result in the title. After spending a day or so failing to prove it, I looked for a proof in some standard texts. Not everyone uses the same definitions, so for clarity:

(1) $X$ is regular means you can separate points and closed sets with open sets;

(2) $X$ is Lindelöf if every open cover has a countable subcover;

(3) $X$ is paracompact if every open cover has a locally finite refinement.

In Munkres' *Topology*, 2nd ed, the proof seemed to be largely in Lemma 41.3, although not in a particularly helpful form. With several details filled in (and irrelevant material omitted), it seems to be:

--- start of proof ---

1. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be any open cover of $X$. Take any $x\in X$ and any $A\in\mathcal{A}$ which contains $x$. Then $X\setminus A$ is closed and $x\notin X\setminus A$. Since $X$ is regular, we can find two disjoint open sets $U,V$ st $x\in U$ and $X\setminus A\subset V$. So the closed set $C=X\setminus V\subset A$. Since $U,V$ are disjoint, we also have $U\subset C$. But $\overline{U}$ is the smallest closed set containing $U$, so we must have $\overline{U}\subset C\subset A$. Hence $U\in\mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is defined as the collection of all open subsets of $X$ whose closure is contained in an element of $\mathcal{A}$. So $\mathcal{B}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{A}$ and an open cover of $X$.
2. Since $X$ is Lindelöf, $\mathcal{B}$ has a countable subcover $\mathcal{C}=\{B_1,B_2,B_3,\dots\}$. Let $D_1=\overline{B_1},D_2=\overline{B_2}\setminus B_1,D_3=\overline{B_3}\setminus(B_1\cup B_2),D_4=\overline{B_4}\setminus(B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3)$ etc. Then $\mathcal{D}=\{D_1,D_2,D_3,\dots\}$ covers $X$ and consists of closed sets. Take any $x\in X$. Let $k$ be the smallest integer such that $x\in B_k$. Each point in $B_k$, which is an open nei of $x$, belongs to at least one of $D_1,\dots,D_k$ but not to any other $D_i$ and hence $B_k$ intersects just finitely many sets in $\mathcal{D}$. In other words, $\mathcal{D}$ is locally finite. Also $D_i\subset\overline{B_i}$ which is a subset of some element of the cover $\mathcal{A}$, so $\mathcal{D}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{A}$.
3. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the collection of all open sets that intersect only finitely many $D_i$. Because $\mathcal{D}$ is locally finite, $\mathcal{E}$ covers $X$. Applying the result in paras 1-2 to $\mathcal{E}$, we can find a refinement $\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{E}$ such that: (i) $\mathcal{F}$ covers $X$; (ii) $\mathcal{F}$ is locally finite; (iii) every set in $\mathcal{F}$ is closed.
4. For $i=1,2,3,\dots$, let $C_i$ be the union of all sets $F\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $F\cap D_i=\emptyset$. We claim that each $C_i$ is closed. For suppose $x\notin C_i$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is locally finite we can find an open nei $U$ of $x$ which only intersects finitely many members of $\mathcal{F}$, and hence only intersects finitely many of those whose union is $C_i$. Call those $F_1,\dots,F_k$. Now $F_1,\dots,F_k$ are members of $\mathcal{F}$ and hence closed, so $F_1\cup\dots\cup F_k$ is closed and $U'=U\setminus(F_1\cup\dots\cup F_k)$ is open. So $U'$ is an open set which contains $x$ but does not intersect $C_i$. Hence $x\notin\overline{C_i}$. Hence $C_i$ is closed.
5. Let $E_i=X\setminus C_i$. So $E_i$ is open and $D_i\subset E_i$ and hence $\{E_1,E_2,E_3,\dots\}$ is an open cover for $X$.
6. For each $D_i$ take an element $A_i\in\mathcal{A}$ containing $D_i$, and let $G_i=E_i\cap A_i$. Evidently, the collection $\mathcal{G}=\{G_1,G_2,G_3,\dots\}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{A}$ and consists of open sets. Since $D_i\subset E_i$ and $D_i\subset A_i$, we have $G_i\supset D_i$, and hence $\mathcal{G}$ is an open cover of $X$.
7. It remains to show that $\mathcal{G}$ is locally finite. Given any $x\in X$, we can find a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ which intersects only finitely many members of $\mathcal{F}$ (because $\mathcal{F}$ is locally finite). Since $\mathcal{F}$ covers $U$, the sets in $\mathcal{F}$ which intersect $U$ must cover it. So it is enough to show that if $F\in\mathcal{F}$ intersects $U$, then it only intersects finitely many members of $\mathcal{G}$. But $\mathcal{F}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{E}$ and so by definition $F$ intersects only finitely many members of $\mathcal{D}$. But if $F$ intersects $G_i$, then it intersects $E_i\supset G_i$ and hence $F\not\subset C_i$ and so $F\cap D_i\neq\emptyset$. Hence if $F$ intersects infinitely many members of $\mathcal{G}$, then it intersects infinitely many members of $\mathcal{D}$. Contradiction. So $\mathcal{G}$ is locally finite and we are done. $\Box$

--- end of proof ---

That is all most ingenious, but far more complicated and hard to understand than I expected. My question is simply whether anyone knows of any better proofs. Of course, you can usually shorten proofs by using enough lemmas or theorems. The proof above uses little beyond the basic definitions. So I am interested in better arguments rather than pushing things into lemmas.

Answer (score 3):

In [this note](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/03.pdf) I wrote up the proof of a classic characterisation of paracompactness for regular spaces (write-up based on my old lecture notes, Engelking and papers by E. Michael). It has the Lindelöf fact as a trivial corollary, as I also note there. The ideas are very similar to the proof you sketched. You’ll recognise many elements.

Comment: Thank you for that (+1). I guess you are saying (1) my write-up of Munkres proof is probabaly ok, and (2) I shouldn't expect to find anything much simpler. Both (1) and (2) are helpful, but I think I will wait a while to see if anyone comes up with anything else before accepting the answer!

Comment: @almagest it’s also an appreciation for taking the time to formulate a question. Many just dump their homework without thinking. I like questions that show effort.

Comment: I last did a course on general topology around 1969! That was well before most Nagata-Smirnov etc work on metrization was even mentioned in undergraduate work. After a lifetime largely frittered away outside of math, I am discovering that (1) my brain needs some intensive rewiring - I simply cannot think as fast as I could in the 1960s, and (2) there have been quite a few advances in math since then, but disappointingly few radical revisions of the undergraduate syllabus. It is a pity someone cannot be persuaded to do for math what Dick Feynman did for physics in 1961/2.